# Why when I promote the widget to a class this error is shown? "C1083: Cannot open include file: 'glwidget.h': No such file or directory"

Tags: c++, qt

This is the tutorial I was trying to do:

[tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1nzHSkY4K18)

I am using qt version 5.4 and msvc2013.

[image: versions]

I do not if this is correct in Qt5

And in FORM ".ui" I created a "Widget Component". And, I created a Class to use Opengl functions. The problem is:

1. If I run without promote the "Widget Component" to my Class, the Qt build very well.
2. HOWEVER, when I promote, this message is shown:

   ```
   Error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QGLWidget': No such file or directory
   ```

**THIS IS MY FILE .pro:**

```
QT       += core gui opengl

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = TesteOpenGL2
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
    glwidget.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    glwidget.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

**THIS IS MY HEADER FILE OF CLASS "glwidget.h":**

```
#ifndef GLWIDGET_H
#define GLWIDGET_H

#include <QGLWidget>

class GLWidget : public QGLWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
   explicit GLWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);   

   virtual void initializeGL();
   virtual void paintGL();
   virtual void resizeGL(int w, int h);

};

#endif // GLWIDGET_H
```

**THIS IS MY SOURCE FILE OF CLASS "glwidget.cpp":**

```
#include "glwidget.h"
#include <QGLWidget>

GLWidget::GLWidget(QWidget *parent) :
    QGLWidget(parent)

{

}
void GLWidget::initializeGL()
{

}

void GLWidget::paintGL()
{

}

void GLWidget::resizeGL(int w, int h)
{

}
```

**THIS IS UI FILE CONTENT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>574</width>
    <height>425</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
   <widget class="GLWidget" name="widget" native="true">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>60</x>
      <y>40</y>
      <width>481</width>
      <height>291</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menuBar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>574</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="menuArquivo">
    <property name="title">
     <string>Arquivo</string>
    </property>
    <addaction name="actionSair"/>
   </widget>
   <addaction name="menuArquivo"/>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QToolBar" name="mainToolBar">
   <attribute name="toolBarArea">
    <enum>TopToolBarArea</enum>
   </attribute>
   <attribute name="toolBarBreak">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </attribute>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusBar"/>
  <action name="actionSair">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Sair</string>
   </property>
  </action>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>GLWidget</class>
   <extends>QWidget</extends>
   <header>glwidget.h</header>
   <container>1</container>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

**Why when I promote the widget to a class this error is Shown?**

Comment: share the .ui file content

Comment: Has been shared.

Comment: The .ui contradicts what you indicate since according to what I see you have promoted the class `MyOpenGLWidget` that is implemented in the file `myopenglwidget.h` that according to your .pro does not exist. Change all `MyOpenGLWidget` to `GLWidget` and `myopenglwidget.h` to `glwidget.h` in your .ui file

Comment: Sorry, I have been changed the file. I fixed now the Ui content. 

This is the tutorial I was trying to do:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W3-SMvMa8D4&t=18s

Comment: change `explicit GLWidget(QObject *parent = 0);` to `explicit GLWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);` and `GLWidget::GLWidget(QObject *parent) :
    QGLWidget(parent)` to `GLWidget::GLWidget(QWidget *parent) :
    QGLWidget(parent)`

Comment: I have already tryed this in my firt tried. The QObject is already my second tried.

Both does not run, and the same error apear.

Comment: I read in google that windows SDK maybe can be the problem, but I do not know how to change the SDK in QT. I know change this in the Visual Studio, but not in the Qt5 (I am newbei yet in Qt).

Comment: Recommendation: Delete the build folder as sometimes the cache generates some problems.

Comment: I did it a lot. before  every run I delete the build folder, and the same problem.

Comment: If you change all QGLWidget for QWidget then you still have that problem?

Comment: yes. I put a image of the version auto-detected in QT5. maybe if somebory knows something about that version.

Comment: FIXED: just delete this line "greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets" in the FILE. ".pro"